# CV2 frame from video issue

Tags: python-3.x, video-capture, opencv, python

I am trying to get a frame from a video. However, when I try to print the image to see the array, I get none. Also I would like to get the 20th frame from the video. Please find the code below. Would anyone be able to help me regarding this.

Code:

```
    cap= cv2.VideoCapture('/media/michael/extHDD/Kaggle/DeepFAke/DF_all/aarr.mp4')
    while(cap.isOpened()):
       ret, frame = cap.read()
       if ret == False:
          break
    print(frame)
```

Output:

`None`

Thanks & Best Regards

Michael

Answer (score 0):

I found for the `None` issue. To get the answer I need to indent the `print(frame)` so that it starts from under the `IF` command.

Corrected code below;

```
cap= cv2.VideoCapture('/media/michael/extHDD/Kaggle/DeepFAke/DF_all/aarr.mp4')
    while(cap.isOpened()):
       ret, frame = cap.read()
       if ret == False:
          break
       print(frame)
```

Would like to know how to get the 20th frame from the video though.

Thanks & Best Regards

Michael